# using nowdoc from php method to store texts in arrays in fat-free-framework

Tags: fat-free-framework

I am working on page which is going to present 20 products. I would like to avoid using any db(page is going to be simple) so I am thinking about storing products' data in [globals] array. Case is that each product description is quite long between 500 and 1000 words and it is formatted which makes this very complicated. I am wondering if is possible to use similiar to nowdoc from php method to manage such long texts in free-fat-framework frane(http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc)

Do you have any other idea to store long text in arrays in 3f?
Thanks in advance
Macrin

Answer (score 0):

The [user guide](https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/framework-variables#[globals]) has an example of a very long string:

```
[globals]
str="this is a \
very long \
string"
```

Me, I would keep each product's description (with any other info, like photo url or price) in a seperate text file in a dedicated directory (let's say `products`). Then in `index.php` or any other route handler I would scan this directory and load the descriptions:

```php
$productsDir = dir(__DIR__ . '/products');
$productsInfo = [];
foreach (new DirectoryIterator($productsDir) as $fileInfo) {
    if($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;
    $productsInfo[] = file_get_contents($fileinfo->getPathname());
}
var_dump($productsInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JIG database and its data mapper.
https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/jig-mapper

It can store your product items in plain `.json` files and you also get some basic CRUD and search functionality. You can also hook in [Cortex](https://github.com/ikkez/f3-cortex) later, if you ever want to upgrade to a real DB.